# Can one typeset latex to look like Bourbaki's books?

Tags: fonts

Can LaTeX produce text as in the Bourbaki books? Specifically, the fonts and math symbols.

Here is a sample (thanks to percusse):

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a clue as to what exactly you are having problems reproducing? Taking a quick look, I don't see that the linked book is anything particularly out of the ordinary.

Comment: If you are still interested, you should visit [overleaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com/). There is a template of the [Societé Mathématique de France](https://www.overleaf.com/12162619pmjtymyyhpwq#/46205779/) (in fact a journal and book templates) which look nice.  If you finally got the Bourbaki's template say me how please.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think the only difficulty is how to get french mathematical typopgraphy: all capital letters are in roman, as are all greek letters. Moreover, `\leqslant` and `\geqslant` are used, instead of `\leq` and `\geq`. Some font packages, such as MinionPro or kpfonts have a frenchmath option.
As for the general layout, you can use the `geometry` and `titlesec` packages. The layout of theorems, definitions, examples can be obtained with the `ntheorem` package (there is a `\theoremindent` length, which would be useful for the layout of examples).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Furthermore you don't have to sign with your name, as it will automatically be display in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: For french style you can use `newtxmath package` with the option `frenchmath`. At least, that works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I just checked that the english edition of Bourbaki is published by Springer. It is very likely that the font they used is Minion, since Springer developped  8 or 10 years ago a font named Sminion, which is a slightly darker version of Adobe Minion. So you can try the `MinionPro` package together with `Mnsymbols`.

Comment: The font in the sample shown in the question is Baskerville (easily recognizable by its open lowercase g). The closest existing LaTeX font is probably [SMF Baskerville](http://cahiers.gutenberg.eu.org/cg-bin/article/CG_1999___32_5_0.pdf), but it's not publicly available.

Comment: @BernardAlfonsi Perhaps consider editing your other answer to include this information too: most of the time a single answer per person works best. Also, I wonder if you could respond to Philippe's point?