# Template to use mathspec for old-fashion text. Step 1: _Ho do I use `mathspec` and `fontspec`?_

Tags: fonts, fontspec, mathspec, kpfonts, math-fonts

**(Edited after some comments)**

I think this is y most difficult question, so I apologize in advance if I do not explain myself well or is a very strange question.

I would like to get an old-fashion text and I'm thinking use `mathspec` and `fontspec` packages for that. For example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70541/can-one-typeset-latex-to-look-like-bourbakis-books) is a question about get bourbaki's style book. But the mos detailed answer uses `MinionPro` package and I haven't lincese. Also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338765/font-of-old-math-books?rq=1) is an answer to change the body font (although the used font isn't free).

For my pourpose I have decided use `fontspec' and`mathspec`. But I don't know how they works. So, can anybody help me with that?
My`mwe` (it doesn't work and I don't know why) is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%Basics
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

%Math
%\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%Theorems
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
  \newtheoremstyle{theorem}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}% measure of space to indent
  {\scshape}% name of head font
  {.~---}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
\declaretheorem[style=theorem,name=numberwithin=section]{theorem}

%fontspec and mathspec packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathspec}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] $\sqrt{-g}$.

\begin{equation}
G_{im} = 0 
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]

\[
\Gamma_{ab}^c = \Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\rho .
\]

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[3]:

\[
\sum_{i=1}^n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
\]

\end{theorem}

\lipsum[4]

\[
\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\kappa \pi\omega\dots
\]


\end{document}
```

There are other related questions to the old-style apparence, such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9894/old-style-antique-typesetting-in-latex-tex?rq=1).

Thank you so much.

PD: Use `kpfonts` for my pourpose is suggested in some of these questions. Anyway, I don't know use any of these packages so... Ifi you think `kpfonts` is beter for my actual pourpose please feel yourself free to answer my question ''How do I use it?'' by the moment) with `kpfonts` instead of the others.

Comment: Please provide code for a minimal document which shows what you have so far and please note that the site works best when you ask one question per ... well, per question, actually. Right now, you are asking for at least two different much-too-big things. Questions should focus on resolving a particular technical issue and not be vague requests for two or more new packages!

Comment: You can use any font available on your system with `fontspec`. (Er ... mostly.) For mathematics, you need specialised fonts: either fonts which MATH table support or fonts for traditional maths typesetting. I strongly recommend starting with the LaTeX Font Catalogue unless you have a suitable MATH-table-supporting font available.

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but this is not a place *to give you a detailed template*, you can create one on your own by reading an introduction, we can help with small things. If you want a template for free, please have a look at [LaTeX Typesetting](http://www.latextypesetting.com/).

Comment: @Johannes_B: No no no, I don't want the whole template, but only the `fontspec`and `mathspec` commands. When I said `template` I mean these commands with an explanation to be able to change the options in the future.

Comment: @cfr: I mentioned `kpfonts` package just so you feel free answering with the package that is easiest for you. It was not my intention ask two questions.  For the `mwe` I'll give one in a couple of minutes.

Comment: So, your question is: *How do i use `fontspec` and `mathspec`*? The question has nothing to do with old fonts, margins, layout etc. All this is just clutter in the question that makes people misunderstand.

Comment: @Johannes_B: mmm, Im thinking cfr may have reason. Somehow, implicitly, I wanted to know how to get the look of bourbaki's book taking advantage at the same time to know how these packages are used. And that that are two questions, as cfr said before. But Johannes_B your question is rightly what I want for the moment. I'll edit the question

Comment: If you click on the `fontspec` and `mathspec` tags at the bottom of your question, you will find plenty of examples. Or you could `texdoc <package>` to see the packages' documentation, of course. How to use `fontspec` is rather a large question and the answer depends on a whole range of factors. How to use `mathspec` is a little more contained, but how to work around its bugs and limitations rather less so. Almost certainly you should start by removing `fontenc`.

Comment: Anyway, I sincerely welcome you on TeX.SE :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't the desired answer yet, but duirng this time I've found some examples and answers in this foro and I want to share them all together, and close this answer.

**First** Using times new roman, which seems quite old (at least for me). The code I have is

```
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}% Times (No coproduct symbol)
\newcommand\imCMsym[4][\mathord]{%
  \DeclareFontFamily{U} {#2}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{#2}{m}{n}{
    <-6> #25
    <6-7> #26
    <7-8> #27
    <8-9> #28
    <9-10> #29
    <10-12> #210
    <12-> #212}{}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{CM#2} {U} {#2}{m}{n}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{#4}{#1}{CM#2}{#3}
}
\newcommand\alsoimCMsym[4][\mathord]{\DeclareMathSymbol{#4{#1}{CM#2}{#3}}
\let\jmath\relax
\let\amalg\relax
\let\coprod\relax
\let\bigcoprod\relax
\imCMsym{cmmi}{124}{\jmath}
\imCMsym[\mathop]{cmsy}{113}{\amalg}
\imCMsym[\mathop]{cmex}{96}{\coprod}
\alsoimCMsym[\mathop]{cmex}{97}{\bigcoprod}
```

This extra lines are needed to define some symbols which are not defined with this font (at least something like that said the post).

**Second** Using `\mathspec` and `mathastext` packages. This option needs to download (legally or illegaly) Baskerville font. Obviusly, it is thought for persons who don't have the license and can download it only for plain text (not in mathematics). Otherwise they could get Bourbaki's style easily.

```
%fontspeck and mathspeck packages
\usepackage[frenchmath]{mathastext}
\usepackage{mathspec} % https://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle}
    \setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Baskerville}
    \setmathfont{Baskerville}
    \setmathsfont(Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Regular]{GFS     Baskerville}
\setmathsfont(Digits){Old Standard} % because Solomos' "1" wasn't as good
\setmathsfont(Latin)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Italic]{Baskerville}% download GFS's fonts from http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/
```

**Finally** I found this option, which imports symbols from another font and uses unicode data. It doesn't works for me, but may be interesting for someone.

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{GFS Baskerville}
\setmathfont[range="21A6]{latinmodern-math.otf}%  ↦  from LM math "0 ordinary; "1 operator; "2 relation, "3 binary operation
\Umathcode`=="2 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `=
\Umathcode`×="3 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `× \def\times{×}
\Umathcode`↦="3 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `↦ \def\mapsto{↦}
\Umathcode`∂="0 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `∂ \def\partial{∂}
\Umathcode`∅="0 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `∅ \def\emptyset{∅}
\Umathcode`∈="2 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `∈ \def\in{∈}
\Umathcode`∫="1 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `∫ \def\intop{∫}
\Umathcode`⊂="2 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `⊂ \def\subset{⊂}
```

**Final comment** All these codes are a mix of different answers posted in this foro. Nonetheless, the last is actually copy/paste, since I don't understand that package and I don't know how it runs.