# Free alternatives to the fonts used by Bourbaki

Tags: fonts, typography

According to this question: [Can one typeset latex to look like Bourbaki's books?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70541/can-one-typeset-latex-to-look-like-bourbakis-books) the font used by Springer to publish Bourbaki's works is <s>a variant of Adobe Minion</s> Baskerville.

[image: goal]

However, this font is expensive and I was wondering if any free alternative which look similarly was available; for both maths and text. The uppercase π is particularly important for me.

## Suggestions

### Baskervaldx

```latex
\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx} % tosf in text, tlf in math
\usepackage[baskervaldx,vvarbb]{newtxmath} % math italic letters from Baskervaldx
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit
```

[image: baskervaldx]

The *p* looks perfect but the ∏ is very different from the original.

Comment: The font is actually Baskerville, as a commenter notes. You could try using the `baskervaldx` package.

Comment: I added your suggestion to the original post along with commentaries. Thanks!

Comment: Is the question still unsolved?

Comment: Yes it is, the solution I upvoted was close enough but not perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Package `mathastext` with the `eulergreek` option to use Greek letters from the Euler font gives a result that is similar to what you are looking for, at least for the product symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx} % tosf in text, tlf in math
\usepackage[baskervaldx,vvarbb]{newtxmath} % math italic letters from Baskervaldx
\usepackage[italic,eulergreek]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
récurrent sur $p$ le composé $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^p x_i$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The line thickness is supposed to be constant, this is what characterizes Bourbaki's ∏.

Comment: The `fdsymbol` package has the `\prod` symbol with uniform line thickness. Try replacing `\usepackage[italic,eulergreek]{mathastext}` with `\usepackage{fdsymbol}`.

Comment: A bit narrow and too thick but you are getting close, thank you